# Releasing a interpreter lock from another thread/forcing another thread to block

Tags: python, multithreading

Is it possible to release a lock from another running thread by using the multithreading module? The use case that I am working toward is to temporarily force a thread to block and later unblock it.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def loop_forever():
    while True:
        pass

def pause_evaluation():
    #Some code here that will force the other thread to release its GIL

def resume_evaluation():
    #Some code here that will allow other thread to reacquire its GIL

def kill_evaluation():
    global p_1
    p_1.terminate()

def control_evaluation():
    pause_evaluation()
    time.sleep(30)
    resume_evaluation()
    time.sleep(30)
    kill_evaluation()

p_1 = Process(target = loop_forever)
p_2 = Process(target = control_evaluation)

p_1.start()
p_2.start()
p_1.join()
p_2.join()
```

Comment: What is `multithreading`, and where does it come from? It's not a standard library module.

Comment: sorry I meant multiprocessing

Comment: Okay, so when you say "thread" you actually mean "process", right?

Comment: Yes because I believe that it is impossible to do this using multiple threads in python. The GIL prevents threads from being truly concurrent.

Comment: In that case you're talking about wanting to make another *process* release its GIL. Why do you want to do that? I think we need more context for this question to make sense. It sounds like your question actually has nothing to do with the GIL: you just want to be able to pause execution of one process from another.

Comment: "The GIL prevents threads from being truly concurrent." <- Depends what those threads are doing. If they're all CPU-bound threads doing calculations that don't release the GIL, then yes. Otherwise, it's not quite so clear cut. It's perfectly possible to have a CPU-bound thread running in parallel with an I/O-bound thread, for example, because most I/O operations release the GIL.

Comment: To clarify, I have two cpu bound threads A and B that are producers and consumers respectively. I want thread A to temporarily pause B immediately without waiting for B to finish its current process.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly from `threading` or `multiprocessing`, as manual management of GIL release requires too many things to easily offer it as part of a Python-layer API.

If you are willing, you can instead create a C extension module and specifically manage threadsafety. The common pattern for a manually-created C extension is like this:

```
#include "Python.h"
...

PyObject *manager_function(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
   ...
   Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
   // Place threaded C code here.  
   // Disallowed from using Python API functions
   ...
   Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
   ...
   return result;
}
```

And in Cython there is the `nogil` context manager, such as [described here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#nogil).

I think a low-cost solution for you would be to investigate `cython.parallel` and `nogil` options in Cython, because it might not be too hard to port your code over to Cython, and simply use `cdef` for everything but one Python "driver" function.

As others pointed out in the comments, the CPython interpreter has a few ways in which it decides to release the GIL. The most common is that it will de facto release the GIL after a certain number of op codes have been processed in the main interpreter loop (a default of 100, which can be adjusted with `sys.setcheckinterval` and which can be viewed with `sys.getcheckinterval`).

Additionally, when the interpreter recognizes a thread that is waiting on I/O, it may release the GIL. In that case, even in GIL'd Python, you would be achieving concurrent computing via plain old threading. Some thread would happily execute interpreter op codes meanwhile another thread is waiting for a socket read signal or something from some I/O source.

Eventually, the GIL will be released again at a time when the I/O thread is ready to complete the read, and the program will cease being concurrent and resume fully synchronous execution across multiple threads. This all happens behind the scenes and is not explicitly managed by the programmer.

Comment: Note: The `set-` and `getcheckinterval` functions are no longer relevant in Python 3.2+, where the GIL was completely revamped (multiple CPU bound threads still don't _gain_ anything, but unlike Python 2.x-3.1, you don't use 1.5 cores and get 0.75 cores worth of work done, with the balance going toward GIL contention overhead).

Comment: Indeed, that's a very important point. Those functions still exist in `sys` in Python 3 newer versions, but they don't really mean the same thing given the rewrite of the GIL itself.